# Navigation Link Destination wrapped in NavigationView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly use `NavigationView` correctly in SwiftUI. What I have currently is a `NavigationView` with a list inside it. This `List` has `NavigationLink` as it's rows. The `NavigationLink` has another view with a `NavigationView` as it's destination. The issue is that the second view/destination view's navigation bar has a huge empty space as you can see below.

[image]

I tried removing the `NavigationView` view from the second view but then the toolbar stops working.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [Item] = [
        Item(title: "Apple"),
        Item(title: "Banana"),
        Item(title: "Papaya"),
        Item(title: "Mango")
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        SecondView()
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.title)
                    }

                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("ContentView")
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @State private var items: [Item] = [
        Item(title: "Carrot"),
        Item(title: "Cucumber"),
        Item(title: "Lettuce")
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.title)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("SecondView")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @unknown, please add sample code

Comment: added some sample code, you should be able to recreate the issue with it.

Comment: You don't need `NavigationView` in destination, just remove it. All links stacked into root navigation view. (You would try to search first - there were hundreds of same questions).

Comment: @Asperi, man you're too fast ;)

Comment: @Asperi As I mentioned in the question, when I remove the `NavigationView` the toolbars added to the `NavigationView` doesn't work properly(doesn't recognize button touches).

Comment: But then again it might be an issue with the toolbar implementation, which i will now look into.